# android studio don't make jar file

Tags: java, android, jar

`unity` and android `peristalsis` I want.

but android jar file does not occur.

I can not see the stackoverflow statement.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}

task deleteOldJar(type : Delete){
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}

task exportJar(type:Copy){
    from('build.intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar','CustomLibrary.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar,build)
```

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: please format the question (images) correctly

Comment: does your jar appear in `build.intermediates/bundles/release/`?